# How to reset a NSMutableString with a empty value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Suppose str has right know a value "me".

And On click of a button I want that the value of str get reset. That is the string value become nil or empty.

now i am using this `[myword stringWithString: @""];` but not working.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [setString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/setString:) with "" as parameter.

```
[myWord setString:@""];
```

And if you want to make it nil, then release it and then set it to nil.

```
[myWord release];
myWord = nil;
```